# AndroidTestCase - Asynch calls

Tags: android

I am writing unit tests (AndroidTestCase).  The application under test uses some background services to communicate over the web the get information.

To receive notification of events I am interested in, (like when content has been delivered etc), I register a listener that exposes various methods.  In these listener interface methods, I assert certain things to help me validate i am getting appropriate responses.

My problem is that the test methods are finishing prior to the callback occurring and I do not know how to tell the method to "wait" for the callback to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for all background thread work... it makes life oh-so-much easier.

Then in your [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) implementation, which will run on the UI thread once the worker thread is completed, you can run your test methods.